# SQL duplicate rows with reference to other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables which are designed like this.

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(200)
);

CREATE TABLE job
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(200),
    emp_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
);

insert  into employee (id, name) values (1, 'user1');
insert  into employee (id, name) values (2, 'user2');
insert  into employee (id, name) values (3, 'user3');
insert  into job (id, name, emp_id) values (1, 'job1', 1);
insert  into job (id, name, emp_id) values (2, 'job2', 2);
insert  into job (id, name, emp_id) values (3, 'job3', 3);
insert  into job (id, name, emp_id) values (4, 'job3', 3);
```

And what I need is
**a query**
to duplicate user1,2,3 into 4,5,6, but meanwhile, a old set of job 1,2,3,4 that are referenced with user 1,2,3 will be copied as job 5,6,7,8 and the new user 4,5,6 will have reference to the new 5,6,7,8.

So the result before the query.

```
Job Table:
id  name    emp_id
1   t_job1  1
2   t_job2  2
3   t_job3  3
4   t_job3  3

Employee table:
id  name
1   user1
2   user2
3   user3
```

After running the query for duplicating user1,2,3:

```
Job Table:
id  name    emp_id
1   t_job1  1
2   t_job2  2
3   t_job3  3
4   t_job3  3
5   t_job1  4
6   t_job2  5
7   t_job3  6
8   t_job3  6

Employee table:
id  name
1   user1
2   user2
3   user3
4   user1
5   user2
6   user3
```

This is an ideal case, but in the code we really work on, there is indefinite amount of job and employee relationship.

So how could this be achieved with query?
For one thing, I cannot change the table structure, if I could, I would.

Attach the link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de15f/1

We are using oracle, but I put the example under MySQL.

Comment: Why all the db platform tags?  Question is unclear.  Solutions may vary by platform.

Comment: Removed the unrelated platforms.

Comment: make a more clearer result here maybe.

Comment: Tried to add an example to see if it is clearer

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate your users?

Comment: Sorry, but this is the query we need to build.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the answer may depend on the database system that's being used. Below mentioned is a working code built for SQL Server. Hope this helps. :-)

```
DECLARE @NewEmployee AS TABLE (id INT, [name] VARCHAR(200));
DECLARE @NewJob AS TABLE (id INT, [name] VARCHAR(200), emp_id INT);

DECLARE @Max INT, @i INT = 0;

INSERT INTO @NewEmployee (id, [name])
SELECT e.id + m.MaxId, e.[name]
FROM employee e
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT max(id) MaxId FROM employee) m;

INSERT @NewJob (id, [name])
SELECT J.id + m.MaxId id, J.[name]
FROM job j
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT max(id) MaxId FROM job) m;

SELECT @Max = MAX(id), @i = MAX(id) - COUNT(1) + 1 FROM @NewJob;

WHILE @i <= @Max
BEGIN
    UPDATE nj
    SET nj.emp_id = ISNULL(ne.id, me.id)
    FROM @NewJob nj
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(id) id FROM 
                (   SELECT e.id id FROM @NewEmployee e
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT emp_id id FROM @NewJob) T) ne
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(e.id) id FROM @NewEmployee e) me
    WHERE nj.id = @i
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

INSERT INTO employee
SELECT * FROM @NewEmployee;

INSERT INTO job
SELECT * FROM @NewJob;

SELECT * FROM employee;
SELECT * FROM job;
```